# Sharepoint 2013 version degrade

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I was trying to edit the masterpage of my site by referencing a css file and when i saved it, the site version got degraded to SP 2010 or 07.
Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Did you select a v4 master rather than a 15 master to apply to your site?  If so, just try switching the master to see if that would begin to correct the issue. Then add your css reference to the 15 version master.

Comment: I am new to this, v4 master is the only one i can see on designer, how do i switch to 15?

Comment: I was referring to the Master Page setting in Site Settings > Look and Feel.  This reflects the master pages from the master page gallery.  If you look in the master page gallery you'll see that seattle.master and oslo.master are version 15 masters.

Answer (score 2):

Change the master to a version 15 (2013 experience) master.  Navigate to Site Settings > Look and Feel > Master Page and select either the seattle.master or oslo.master.